# element.getElementsByTagName is not a function error in jsPDF

Tags: jquery, jspdf, html2canvas

When I use `$('.mySelector').html()` instead of `document.body` in the following call to jsPDF I get this error:

> element.getElementsByTagName is not a function

How can I use a jQuery selector with jsPDF?

```html
<div class="mySelector">
  <p>HTML content...</p>
</div>
<button onclick="pdfDowload();">PDF</button>
```

```js
function pdfDowload() {
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
  pdf.addHTML(document.body, function() {
    pdf.save('report.pdf');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding `$('.mySelector').get(0)` this code after downloading I was getting blank page. But I have solved this issue instead of `pdf.addHTML` using `pdf.fromHTML` in the following code

```
function pdfDowload() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
    pdf.fromHTML($('.mySelector').html());
    pdf.save('report.pdf');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because, according to the [documentation](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#addHTML), jsPDF expects the argument provided to that function to be a Element object, not a string.

To fix this you can retrieve the underlying Element from the jQuery object by using `get()`:

```
function pdfDowload() {
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
  pdf.addHTML($('.mySelector').get(0), function() {
    pdf.save('report.pdf');
  });
}
```

Also note that the documentation states that this `addHTML()` method is deprecated. You should follow their guidelines to update your approach.

Comment: Can u give me a jsfiddle link? because after downloading content not showing @Rory McCrossan

Comment: I can't really set up a fiddle for this as it's quite a complex example. However, you should be able to debug this. What does the `$('.mySelector')` return? If there are multiple `.mySelector` elements in the DOM you'll need to loop through them, for example

Comment: It should show "HTML content..." content but not showing in the downloaded pdf file, getting blank

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.mySelector').get(0)
```

Don't use `.html()`

EDIT:
try adding a short pause:

```
pdf.addHTML($('.mySelector').get(0),function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        pdf.save('report.pdf');
      },1000);
)};
```

Comment: This is still showing blank after downloading @ChrisBE

Comment: can you show the lines of code related to jsPDF before the addHTML function?

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>